# mensaje duplicado al ejecutar procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql

Como puedo evitar resultado duplicado por pantalla cuando ejecuto un procedimiento almacenado?

Este es el procedimiento:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `my_procedure`()
BEGIN

declare fecha_aux       varchar(30);
set fecha_aux = Date_format(now(),'%M %d %Y  %h:%i:%s %p');

--Aqui imprimo el texto en la pantalla
select  "%1! SP_PASO_HISTORICO -> Borrado de tablas temporales ", @fecha_aux;

END
```

Salida:

```
mysql> call my_procedure;
+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| %1! SP_PASO_HISTORICO -> Borrado de tablas temporales  | @fecha_aux                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| %1! SP_PASO_HISTORICO -> Borrado de tablas temporales  | November 24 2017  01:35:44 PM |
+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

porque salen 2 mensajes en la pantalla?
Como puedo evitar que salga el primero?
Solo quiero que aparezca:

```
%1! SP_PASO_HISTORICO -> Borrado de tablas temporales  | November 24 2017  01:35:44 PM |
```

¿Es esto posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es un duplicado.

La primera fila es para describir los nombres de las columnas y la segunda fila es tu resultado.  Parecen ser duplicados porque no le asignastes un nombre a las columnas, por lo que MySQL generó un nombre de acuerdo a la expresión en el `SELECT`.

Pero si modificaras el `SELECT` para asignar un alias a las 2 columnas:

```
select  "%1! SP_PASO_HISTORICO -> Borrado de tablas temporales " as col1, 
        @fecha_aux as col2;
```

...entonces el resultado se vería más normal y quedaría obvio que no se trata de una fila duplicada:

```
mysql> call my_procedure;
+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| col1                                                   | col2                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| %1! SP_PASO_HISTORICO -> Borrado de tablas temporales  | November 24 2017  01:35:44 PM |
+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Aun así, si tu intención realmente es la de eliminar esa fila inicial con los nombres de las columnas, esto lo puedes hacer por medio de agregar la opción `-N` cuando lanzas MySQL en consola. Ejemplo:

```
mysql -N -u sstan -p
```

Entonces el resultado sería:

```
mysql> call my_procedure;
+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| %1! SP_PASO_HISTORICO -> Borrado de tablas temporales  | November 24 2017  01:35:44 PM |
+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Entiendo, muchas  gracias. 
Una pregunta mas hay forma de evitar el mensaje "1 row in set (0.00 sec)" después de cada consulta?